# How can I get my two cats to recognize when I'm saying their names?

Tags: cats, training

Recently I lost a 8-month old cat. I had brought him at the age of 1.5 months. Within few days he was able to recognize his name. Now I have bought 2 kittens. They always stick and play together, like they are made for each other. They are attached to us but they don't yet recognize their names.

What should I do in order to make them respond on calling their names?

Comment: Possibly useful: http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/2639/how-can-i-tell-if-my-cat-knows-his-name

Comment: I tried this way on my previous cat, but these two kittens doesn't seem to be friendly with that.

Answer (score 6):

With two or more cats, here is something that has worked for me. Two people stand far apart, with treats in hand. They agree who will call which cat, discussing this without using their names (e.g. I'll call the black cat, you call the white one). Then, on the count of three, they call the cats. Each person only rewards the cat they called. Pretty quickly the cats should learn to respond to their names.

Comment: Be sure the same person does not call the same cat all the time, or you will be teaching a different lesson.